# What other works swords are in the Iron Throne?

Tags: game-of-thrones, behind-the-scenes, object-identification

I recently found out that the prop for the Iron Throne contains several swords from other franchises due to the team just re-using old props and moulds from previous films/shows to save money.

Does anyone know what other swords appear in the Iron Throne?

Comment: are you asking for a list of sword, for example "this sword come from LotR" ?

Comment: @Kepotx Pretty much, what swords that make up the prop came from other movies, etc.

Comment: A little bit off-topic but [bush head](https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fimg.wennermedia.com%2Fsocial%2F1339695178_george-bush-lg.jpg) have been put on a spike

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've had a look around and found a good [IGN article](http://uk.ign.com/articles/2014/03/16/the-iron-throne-may-feature-multiple-movie-swords-including-gandalfs-glamdring) on it which identifies 3 swords.

## Glamdring, The Lord of The Rings

[image: Gamldring]

## Robin of Loxley's blade, Robin Hood

[image: Robin of Loxley's blade]

## Kingdom of Heaven blade

[image: Kingdom of Heaven blade]

Elio also mentions on reddit that he noticed a lot of other Kingdom of Heaven blades in the throne but I can't see any identifiable ones in there.

> Having visited the set during the first season filming, I got a very close look at a protoype of the Throne in a half-completed state that was in their prop room, and I believe you are exactly right that they collected weapon molds from all sorts of sources.
> I specifically recall that several of the swords had marks indicating that they had originated from Ridley Scott's Kingdom of Heaven.
> <sub>[Reddt, Elio_Garcia](https://www.reddit.com/r/asoiaf/comments/208zp5/no_spoilersis_that_gandalfs_sword_in_the_iron/cg18c2w/)</sub>

The above comment by Elio might not be 100% accurate as westerosorg has started a new series called "Westeros.org visits... Northern Ireland Game of Thrones territory". Entry #3 in this has the following information so it isn't entirely clear if these swords made it into the final Iron Throne or just the prototype Elio saw.

> [image: Iron Throne prototype prop piece]
>
> Set Visit entry #3: A piece of an Iron Throne prototype, stored in Props. As I've mentioned before, I got quite a close look at this, and noticed some of them were stamped with "PROPERTY OF KINGDOM OF HEAVEN", meaning they used props from the Ridley Scott film. Rumor has it that Lord of the Rings prop swords also ended up in the throne... #GameOfThrones
>
> <sub>[Instagram, westerosorg](https://www.instagram.com/p/BoPBq7eDsTU/?taken-by=westerosorg)</sub>